# Payment Gateway theoretics

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm new to the community and PHP, so my question may sound stupid to some, but let's get to the point.

I'm learning to use PHP at the moment, and part of it includes implementing an e-payment to an working site. I've read a lot on the net, but I can't figure out some things:

1. Is there a difference between Payment Gateway <-> Payment Processor, or they are used to describe a same thing?
2. When using a third party like Authorize, Paypal, Google Checkout, or something like this, do we really need some hard coding, or can you just stick to the information provided on their sites?
3. I looked through some of the (I think) major payment gateways and I haven't seen any mention of SOAP and WSDL. Are they really needed in a way that I can't find out, or are they are just used rarely and that's why I haven't found any mention of them?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I sound like a noob. Hope to learn faster with your help, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this a tricky business payment gateway differ from one site to another from different 3rd party implementation. u can find the easiest one for you to implement but be careful when u do this. and yes there is a difference between payment gateway and processor which is the processor is what make the payment go to the bank and transfer the money, the gateway make sure the credential that u have enter is correct

happy programing

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`And what about SOAP and WSDL am I missing something or they are just rarely used?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking a Payment processor is a vendero that actually processes payments. Most Payment Processors offer gateways which is the interface you use to submit a payment for processing.

When using a payment processor how much code you have to write is goign to vary with the implementations of the gateway the processor offers and which one of those implementations you choose. Normally there are at least two - some kind of raw API which is the most flexible, and some kind of super simple link to the processor. PayPal Standard and Google Wallet are good examples of the latter, while typical usage of Authorize.net is a good example of the former. IF you use the API generally you need to implement your own order creation process/shopping cart and then you would jsut submit the payment and other details at the end. This allows you to keep everything on you site (not necessarily the data but the experience). The simple route usually involves sending user to the processors site one or more times during the shopping process usually resulting in limited customization and a clear break in user experience.

Some Gateways will use SOAP/WSDL some will use simple REST interfaces, and some will use other implementations. Its generally however they chose to implement in house, but most are going to offer a library to use it for the major scripting languges (PHP,Ruby, Python, C#.Net, VB.net) so odds are you wont have to manually make the calls you'll just utilize the library the provide and deal with the results returned.